# : Custom keyboard shortcuts not working?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

I have started working on a project in MonoDevelop lately, and unlike in VS2010, there is no keyboard shortcut to toggle the comments, and i really liked that shortcut.

Luckily, in OS X you can create custom keyboard shortcuts for any application in System Preferences, like this:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts in System Preferences]

I have put it in All Applications because putting it directly on MonoDevelop.app doesn't work. And by seeing how MonoDevelop doesn't use the OS X UI, but one that looks like Linux, I'm guessing it's not running natively.

As expected, the shortcut was bound to MonoDevelop as well as all the other applications, and it does show up in the menus :

[image]

Everything looked fine until I tried to execute this shortcut, and nothing happened. This is a problem. Does anyone know why the shortcut appears, but is not working? (This only happens in MonoDevelop, I have tried making shortcuts in other applications, and they work.)

Comment: Does it work in a Mono app you made by yourself? Or in some other Mono app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MonoDevelop doesn't use the Mac keybinding system; it has its own: http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/02/06/key_bindings

Comment: Works great, unfortunately I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation. sad_face.jpg